# 'ar' part of model in not stationary error

Tags: r, time-series, arima, stationarity

I have been trying to plot a time series model for the equation

$X_t = 0.5 X_{t-1} + 0.5 X_{t-2} + \epsilon_t$

`set.seed(87364) series5 <- arima.sim(n=1000, list(order = c(2,0,0), ar = c(0.5,0.5)), sd = 1) plot(series5, main = 'AR(2)')`

But I keep getting this error:

`Error in arima.sim(n = 1000, list(order = c(1, 0, 0), ar = c(0.5, 0.5)), : 'ar' part of model is not stationary`

Could someone please help me figure this out? I'm totally new to time series modelling in R

Comment: Hi @Brintha. Your AR (2) process is non-stationary. In particular, an AR(2) must not fail in one of these theoretical 'stability conditions:' **(i)** $\theta_2 + \theta_1 <1$, **(ii)** $\theta_2 - \theta_1 <1$, **(iii)** $|\theta_2| <1$.  Your AR(2) fails on point (i). 7:50 of this lecture provides a good summary: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MpcbUqZ4wzM

Answer (score 1):

You have the following:

$$X_t = 0.5 X_{t-1} + 0.5 X_{t-2} + \varepsilon_t$$

This stochastic process is not stationary. You can see this by inspecting the roots of the characteristic equation:

$$1 - 0.5 x - 0.5 x^2 = 0$$

which you can verify has roots 1 and -2. Since 1 is on the unit circle, the process is not stationary.

Stationarity matters here because you haven't actually fully defined what process you want to simulate from; based on this recursion alone, how do you simulate $X_1$ if you don't have $X_0$ and $X_{-1}$? To fully describe the process, you need to define an initial (joint) distribution for $(X_0,X_{-1})$.

*However*, you can get around this if the conditional distribution implies stationarity, because the process will converge in distribution to the stationarity distribution in the long run, *regardless* of the initial distribution. So, in that case you don't *really* have to specify it. `stats::arima.sim` uses this fact and starts its simulations from the degenerate distribution $X_0=X_{-1}=0$, simulates for an appropriate number of periods as a "burn-in" sample which it then discards, and then continues simulating from there, which should return a sample approximately from the long-run (stationary) distribution. When it can't do that, it refuses to simulate and gives an error.

To solve the problem at hand, you need to specify an initial distribution. This isn't something that you have to find or compute, it's something you have to decide on. This seems to be a question from a textbook, so perhaps there are relevant instructions there. If not, consider the following: since 1 was a root of the characteristic equation and all other roots are outside the unit circle, $\Delta X_t$ is stationary, with recursion:

$$\Delta X_t = -0.5 \Delta X_{t-1} + \varepsilon_t$$

So, the "natural" thing to do is to set $\Delta X_0 \sim \mathcal{N}\left(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{1-(-0.5)^2}\right)$, which is the stationary distribution of $\Delta X_t$. There's no canonical choice for $X_{-1}$, so the degenerate $X_{-1} = 0$ will do. You can simulate approximately from this process like this:

```
arima.sim(n=1000, list(order = c(1, 1, 0), ar = c(-0.5)), sd = 1)
```

If you want different initial conditions, you may be able to exploit argument `start.innov`. Otherwise, you will need to simulate by hand, which shouldn't be very difficult.